# apache port 80 non root

Tags: apache, port, root

How can I use apache port 80 as non root since i know less than 1024 is not recommended.

Comment: You can't, binding a socket to below port 1024 isn't allowed on Linux systems. What's the actual issue with using something above port 1024 or starting the Apache daemon as root?

Comment: I use `5000` or `8080` when I can't run as root. Why aren't you running as root...?

Comment: if i start apache as daemon , will it resolve my issue?

Comment: @user665319: You should probably be starting Apache with init.d scripts or `apache2ctl` if your system has it anyway... the user Apache runs as is controlled by `User` and `Group` directives inside of the your configuration file... all this being said, what is your issue? Do you not have root access to the server you are on?

Answer (score 5):

You have a description of several ways to do that here: [Running network services as a non-root user](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/386).
Discussed are the possibilities of using `iptables`, `authbind` and `sudo`. It's a manual for Debian systems, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure if that's really within the scope of "running as a non-root user", seeing as all of the possibilities discussed require manual setup as a root user and still setup the socket bind as root, something that's really not that much different than just having Apache drop privileges to the designated user in the first place. But, seeing as this is an answer that allows for someone to use privileged ports in an ACL controlled manner and doesn't require modifying the linux kernel source, +1